# noClassDefFoundError with the Selenium webDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jar

i just start using selenium and i've made this little test to try it.
Here the code :

```
package selenium.test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class SeleniumTest {
    static WebDriver driver;
    static Wait<WebDriver> wait;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

        boolean result;
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.name("q"))
            .sendKeys("J'aime bien    les tests");

            driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

            wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
                    System.out.println("Searching ....");
                    return webDriver
                    .findElement(By.id("resultStats")) != null;
                }
            });

        result=driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"))
               .getText()
               .contains("https://en.wikipedia.org
                /wiki/Software_testing");
        } finally {
            driver.close();
        }
        System.out.println("The test " +
        (result ? "succed ! " :  "failed"));
    }
}
```

But when i try to run it i have this noClassDefFoundException :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/open/selenium/WebDriver
>         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper
>        .checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
>          at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>         ... 6 more
>   I'm using eclispe mars, and i don't anderstand because i have added the jar to the buildpahth of the project. Here the jars i've added : [selenium jars](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/selenium-java-2.53.0.zip)
>   I took the selenium-java-2.53.0.jar and the selenium-java-2.53.0-srcs.jar and all the jar in the libs directory.
>   To add the jars i've done:

1. Right click on the project
2. Build Path
3. Add external jars
4. Select all the jars mentioned above.
5. Apply

I can compile the class in eclipse and run it (only in eclipse) but when i want to do it with a terminal it's not working.
What am i doing wrong ?

EDIT : 
I managed to compile the program by using the command :

```
javac -cp C:\selenium-2.53.0\*;C:\selenium-2.53.0\libs\* src\selenium\test\SeleniumTest.java
```

But then when i want to run it with the command :

```
java -cp C:\selenium-2.53.0\*;C:\selenium-2.53.0\libs\*;. selenium.test.SeleniumTest
```

It tells me that my class can't be found.

Comment: do you open build project automatically?

Comment: would you consider use maven for the jar dependecies?

Comment: I use eclipse to compile the project and it give me no error, what is open build project ?

Comment: no i can't use maven

Comment: can you show us your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Did you check JRE System Library ? Are those libraries present?

Comment: i don't have a pom.xml

Comment: the jars i've mentionend are not in the JRE System Library but in the Referenced Libraries,  i compile my class in eclipse but when i want to run it ina terminal it shows the errors write above.

Comment: simple solution use maven or gradle and you shall never see these issues again